# config file syntax for configuring WCF Webservice Client Target EndPoint

Tags: .net, asp.net, wcf

What is the web config syntax for specifying a WCF WebService Proxy's Default Target Endpoint?

Specifically, I'm trying to configure the address that the client uses for locating the .asmx of the webservice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind - found it.
The answer is:

Set the address attribute of the endpoint element.

I.E. `<endpoint address="http://fooland.com/bar.asmx" ... />`

For anyone else who's challenged at searching MSDN like myself, the rest of the documentation for configuring client endpoints can be found at: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731762(VS.85).aspx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.0/ms731762%28v=vs.85%29)